# Creating check-boxes based on list item

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is an excel question :)

I have a list containing x items, when I select `list Item 1`, I want to be able to check checkboxes for each option, then go to `list item 2` and do the same thing.

[Image showing list and checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LVKp.png)

However, I need help linking the checkboxes to each list item. To 'record' the values of the checkboxes per `List Item x`.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is it about a real list box or a list validated cell? A list box does not have such a little arrow to its right side. Then, what you tried by your own? How many list items will be in each such object? Is it a variable number? Are there somehow related check boxes name to the list selections?

Comment: @FaneDuru it has a little arrow to the side as visible in the picture. I do not know the accurate terminology for all the excel elements sorry.

There are 40ish list items in the arrowed cell. Each of those will have 15 checkboxes.

I haven't tried much as I have no idea where to begin, lacking the terminology my google searches are limited

Comment: So, if I would understand that they are Excel cells having a little arrow in their right side, will it be a correct understanding? If yes, did you build the workbook in discussion, or you received it from somebody else? If you build it, did you use list data validation? If so, what range (or a custom list) did you use? If you do not say anything about the list strings content and their relation to the correspondent check boxes, nobody can help you, even if we want helping. Should I understand that there are 40 such validated cells and 600 such check boxes (40 x 15)?

Comment: @FaneDuru, exactly 720 check boxes total to be exact yes !
I made a custom list based on a list of products supplied to me, these are text based values. I did use list data validation to create the list  !
Let me give you an example:

Say i have 2 products: phone and tv (these are the list items)
each list item has the same checkboxes (like in the photo) -> do you use the device (yes/no), do you like the device (yes/no).
When i select tv, i want to be able to tick the boxes, then select phone, and be able to tick those boxes as well (same placement, different results).

Comment: I cannot get you... You were talking about a check box for each validated cell value. Now, you started talking about two check boxes, probably, being checked by answering yes/no . Then, you do not say anything about what will happen with such a check box (supposing that only one is involved) checked as true for a specific product, **when another one is checked**... It is a matter of logic, not VBA. I am afraid that I cannot help you in these circumstances.

Comment: "To 'record' the values of the checkboxes" - where ? on a sheet with 720 rows/columns ?